# Why was this part in S08E21 "Angry Andy", deleted from all platforms, even YouTube?

Tags: the-office, deleted-scenes

In *The Office* (US) S08E21 "Angry Andy", there is a part where Erin makes fun of the way Nellie said "sexual innuendo. Not intentional."

> **Nellie:** Erin, on phone memos you're writing the date American style. Month, day, year. I prefer it day, month, year. Small, bigger, biggest. Oh, sexual innuendo. Not intentional.
>
> **Erin:** Shut up. Shut up! I am sick of your dumb opinions. And if you don't like the way that I take phone messages, here! [throws phone] Take 'em yourself!
>
> **Andy:** Oh, and another thing! Our sex life is none of your businesses!
>
> **Erin:** And Andy is the manager, not Nellie!
>
> **Andy:** Stop protecting me! I'm a man. I can protect myself! This is misdirected anger and I'm sorry! I don't mean to lash out at you! There's a lot coming up right now, all at once! [into phone] Dad go to hell, I'm taller than you!
>
> **Nellie:** Okay, just calm down.
>
> **Andy:** You are not the manager. I earned that job. I was personally chosen after Robert was chosen and quit.
>
> **Robert:** Andy, why don't you just take a seat?
>
> **Andy:** Why don't you take a seat, you idiot? [throws chair]

I could swear I've seen this in earlier times when I've seen *The Office*, however, recently when I watched this episode on Netflix UK, it's gone. I also looked in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eGx5U2_Mj0&t=188s), also gone. Why on Earth has this been deleted?

Comment: For what it's worth I found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbZwk1FZ4XE) that contains the cut scene. The camera angles are also slightly different. Might have just been cut for time

Answer (score 5):

A possible partial answer...

Can you remember where or how you saw the version with the part that you say is missing?

I ask as there is the Producers Cut version of the episode, which is an extended version of the episode, and it was released on DVD only.

Was it this that you possibly saw?

```
[08x21] "Angry Andy"    

"Angry Andy" first aired on April 19, 2012. 
A Producer's Cut was released on the Season 8 DVD on September 4, 2012. 

Original cut: DVD, Syndication, Netflix, iTunes; 
Producer's Cut (33:20): DVD
```

Ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/DunderMifflin/comments/bwujit/list_of_all_alternate_cuts_of_the_office_episodes/

Also:

https://mashable.com/article/the-office-traveling-salesman-episode-netflix-deleted-scenes

> Watching 'The Office' on Netflix? You're missing a few great scenes.
>
> Here's why some Netflix episodes of the show are different from the DVD versions.

> anyone who owns the DVD box sets of The Office will be able to spot some clear inconsistencies between the episodes streaming and those that aired on NBC.

(But they refer to Season 3 episode, "Traveling Salesmen" instead)

Peacock started adding the extended versions for streaming (Season 1 only thus far):

https://www.slashfilm.com/580710/the-office-season-1-superfan-episodes/

https://www.slashfilm.com/575700/the-office-extended-episodes-on-peacock/

> Bloomberg learned about the extended episodes coming to Peacock from Matt Strauss, chairman of Peacock and NBCUniversal Digital Enterprises. The executive said:
>
> "We will be reintroducing 'The Office' in a more complete way, incorporating elements that were not part of the original broadcast."
>
> The extended episodes are likely the producer's cuts, and although they never aired on TV during the original broadcast run of The Office, they were made available on NBC.com after the episodes originally premiered.

https://www.reddit.com/r/DunderMifflin/comments/kplv38/peacock_extended_cuts/

> has anyone watched season 8 e21 angry Andy, I swear I don’t recall so many of these scenes?

Comment: I think I saw it on Amazon Prime, they might have updated it since it first released though.

Comment: The question remains, how do I get those extended uncut versions?